# How can I disable the checkboxes for specific rows on lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning:datatable component:

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columnsPhone}"
                           data="{!v.dataPhone}"
                           keyField="id"
                           selectedRows="{!v.selectedRowsPhone }"
                           onrowselection="{!c.getSelectedPhone }
                           hideCheckboxColumn="false"/>
```

I'm looking to disable the checkboxes just for specific rows based on some conditions.

The documentation for lightning:datatable doesn't talk about disabling checkbox for some rows.

How can I disable the checkboxes on specific rows?

Answer (score 0):

**Just for the information.**

I had the same issue and as a workaround I implemented following.

**Note:** I was using lightning web components

**JS Code**

```
@track selectedRowIds = [];

onRowSelection(event) {
    var rows = event.detail.selectedRows;
    this.selectedRows = [];
    this.selectedRowIds = [];
    rows.forEach(row => {
        if(!mycondition_to_disable) {
            this.selectedRowIds.push(row.Id);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<lightning-datatable onrowselection={onRowSelection}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Then if your condition is met, you cannot select that particular row.